# symfony css-selector is not installed

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, phpunit

When I try to use phpunit I get the following error on one of my tests

```
RuntimeException: Unable to filter with a CSS selector as the Symfony CssSelector is not installed (you can use filterXPath instead).
```

I have symfony/css-selector in both the require and require dev sections and neither seems to help phpunit detect the package.

I assume I need to activate it somewhere. Has anyone had this problem before or know how to fix it?
Thanks

Edit: 
The test itself is just a simple test to get everything working correctly

The test is just a simple example test meant to make sure things are working. The form has one field, a text box called title, and a submit button. When this test is ran the css-selector error is shown.

```
public function test_fill_out_project_create_form()
    {
                $this->visit('project/create')
                ->type('TEST12345','title')
                ->press('Save')
                ->seePageIs('project/')
                ->see('TEST12345');        
    }
```

Comment: What's the code from your test?

Comment: I edited the question with some sample code. it's a very simple example as I want to get everything running correctly before writing any code

Comment: Can you see the css selector component in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/CssSelector`?

Comment: @WouterJ yes the cssSelector component is in that directory, php unit just can't detect it for some reason. Possible permission issue? I am also using Laravel Homestead (vagrant) if that helps

Answer (score 1):

I think Symfony standard edition does not come with CSS Selector component , you can install it fairly easy though:

```
composer require symfony/css-selector
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already added symfony/css selector in my composer.json file.

I also tried adding it to the "require-dev" section and still no luck

Comment: @user1901469 Did you run composer update after that? The error you see is definitely because css-selector component is not installed.

Comment: The CssSelector component is included in the `symfony/symfony` package, so Symfony SE definitely comes with this component. However, as the question is tagged with `[laravel]`, I think @user1901469 is using Laravel?

Comment: @IgorPantović yep I did run composer update afterwards which didn't help. I also tried deleting the vendor folder, lock file, composer cache and running "composer install" which also didn't work. Very weird.    woulterj: yes I am using Laravel 5.2

Comment: @user1901469 Only other reason, if file is there on the system, is that your autoloading setup isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to clear out all of my composer dependencies and cache then re installing everything to fix this issue.

My best guess at the problem was a symlink between the host codebase and the Homestead VM that was actually hosting the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I tried:

```
composer require symfony/symfony
```

then, it worked, but I will be using it only for require-dev